# FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES alternative?

Tags: php, mysql, filter, mariadb, sanitization

PhpStorm tells me that FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES is deprecated. What filter should be used in its stead? I'm using it to sanitise data before it is used to create MariaDB queries.

Comment: FILTER_SANITIZE_ADD_SLASHES reference: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration74.deprecated.php

Comment: Neither should be used for that purpose.

Comment: Don't sanitize data going into the database. Use prepared statements.

Comment: All the MAGIC thingies are hacks that give a false sense of security.  We are better off without them.